# How to join 2 spark sql streams

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

ENV:
Scala spark version: 2.1.1

This is my streams (read from kafka):

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[1]")
  .setAppName("JoinStreams")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("t", DataTypes.StringType),
    StructField("dst", DataTypes.StringType),
    StructField("dstPort", DataTypes.IntegerType),
    StructField("src", DataTypes.StringType),
    StructField("srcPort", DataTypes.IntegerType),
    StructField("ts", DataTypes.LongType),
    StructField("len", DataTypes.IntegerType),
    StructField("cpu", DataTypes.DoubleType),
    StructField("l", DataTypes.StringType),
    StructField("headers", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType))
  )
)
val baseDataFrame = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")
  .option("subscribe", 'topic')
  .load()
  .selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")
  .select(from_json($"json", schema).as("data"))
  .select($"data.*")

val requestsDataFrame = baseDataFrame
  .filter("t = 'REQUEST'")
  .repartition($"dst")
  .withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())

val responseDataFrame = baseDataFrame
  .filter("t = 'RESPONSE'")
  .repartition($"src")
  .withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())

responseDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("responses")
requestsDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("requests")


val dataFrame = spark.sql("select * from requests left join responses ON requests.rowId = responses.rowId")
```

I get this ERROR when starting the application:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Left outer/semi/anti joins with a streaming DataFrame/Dataset on the right is not supported;;
```

How can I join these two streams?
I also try to do direct join and get the same error.
Should I first save it to file and then read it again?
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need Spark 2.3:

"In Spark 2.3, we have added support for stream-stream joins..."

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins